# How to get asmx url from local wsdl file?

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui

I have a file of type wsdl.  How do I get the asmx?WSDL link from this?  I want this url to plug into SOAPUI so that I can consume this service.  I've searched online and the results talk about going the other way, from link to local wsdl file.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just click Browse in SoapUI and add the file